# Nuxt custom plugin exports is not defined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My new Nuxt app is going to be API heavy so I created a new top level folder named `api` and inside of this folder all of the api routes will be defined but currently there is just `users.ts`

In `api/users.ts`:

```
export default $axios => ({

    create(payload: any) {}

    showAll(): any {
        return $axios.get('...');
    }

}
```

And then in my plugins folder I created a module export all of the apis named `plugins/api.ts`:

```
import users from '../api/users';

export defaut ({ app }, inject) => {

    app.api = { usersAPI: users }

}
```

And finally in my `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
...
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/api'
],
...
```

But in the browser when I load the page I am getting `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

I have a suspicion it might be something to do with Typescript but I have followed the Typescript support guide in the documentation and installed `@nuxt/typescript` as a dev dependency and `ts-node` as a normal dependency and changed the file extension of the config file to use `.ts`.

I have also created a `tsconfig.json` file that has:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

default is misspelled. It currently says `export defaut`.

Answer (score 1):

You written `export defaut ({ app }, inject) => {`

But as CQ said it has to be `export default`

Consider using some kind of linter like `eslint` or `tslint` and also some IDE like vscode.